# Recursively and iteratively calculating integrals in Scheme

Tags: scheme, integral

I'm trying to create both recursive and iterative functions for integration in Scheme. So far, I haven't succeeded. How can I calculate integrals in Scheme?

Comment: what kind of integral? show us your code and describe the problem

Answer (score 1):

What kind of integral are you trying to calculate, with what method? If it's helpful for you, in the book [SICP, section 1.3.1](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#%_sec_1.3.1) theres's an explanation on how to approximate integrals using a Scheme procedure. Also in the same book, in the exercise 1.29 it's explained how to calculate an integral using Simpson's Rule, which is a more accurate method of numerical integration - and there's a solution for that exercise in [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1538/9192).